# To get friend list with email adress and date of birth from linkedin using php api

Tags: php, api, email

We have created new APP  in our developer account (https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer) and using API keys and secret key values in PHP.

We have called following method to get friends list of login user:

```
$user1 = $connection->get(
   "people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,date-of-birth,location:(name),picture-url)"
)
```

But this method only returns the first name, last name, id, location array but NOT return email address and date of birth of friends.

e.g we get following response

```
Array ( 
  [firstName] => Test [id] => ASASAS [lastName] => Ltest [location] => Array ( [name] =>  New York City  )
```

We want logged in users Friends list including all possible values of friends account like email address,name,date of birth, location etc. (especially email address & DOB is mandatory)

It it possible to fetch private data of friends using API? Whether it needs any authorized permissions?
OR whether any other API method to use in PHP code?

Answer (score 1):

Only basic profile is available

See basic profile :

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#profile

Comment: Thanks for help Its shows basic profile of login user, but not showing all details of login user's friends

Comment: @user1761289  That is the point - you can't get all details of login user's friends,

Comment: thanks, Is there any way to get email address and date of birth of friends in linked in using PHP -API ? please let us know...